# Включение зависимости в jar с помощью Maven при сборке

Tags: java, maven, jar, include, зависимости

Зависимости включаются в .jar архив следующим образом:

```
me
└───nyanguymf
    └───console.server
doc
META_INF
PacketLib.jar
Thunderbolt.jar
```

А надо так:

```
me
└───nyanguymf
    └───console
        └───server
        └───* содержимое PacketLib.jar *
        └───* содержимое Thunderbolt.jar *
doc
META_INF
```

Использую Maven:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>me.nyanguymf.java.bukkit.console</groupId>
    <artifactId>console-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Java Bukkit remote console</name>

    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.bluecube.thunderbolt</groupId>
        <artifactId>Thunderbolt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Thunderbolt.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>me.nyanguymf.console.net</groupId>
          <artifactId>Packet</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/PacketLib.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

      <plugins>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                  <includes>
                    <include>io.bluecube.thunderbolt:Thunderbolt</include>
                    <include>me.nyanguymf.console.net:Packet</include>
                  </includes>
                </artifactSet>
                <realocations>
                  <realocation>
                    <pattern>io.bluecube.thunderbolt:Thunderbolt</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>io.bluecube.thunderbolt:Thunderbolt</shadedPattern>
                  </realocation>
                  <realocation>
                    <pattern>me.nyanguymf.console.net:Packe</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>me.nyanguymf.console.net:Packet</shadedPattern>
                  </realocation>
                </realocations>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>me.nyanguymf.console.server.ConsoleServer</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
          </plugin>

      </plugins>

    </build>
  </project>
```

Сделал бы через assembly plugin, да вот только мне не все зависимости нужны :D

Answer (score 0):

В итоге понял, что, видимо, Maven не хочет добавлять зависимости из систему, поэтому добавил все нужные зависимости в локальный репозиторий и изменил их загрузку с этого репозитория в секции dependencies.
Вот, что получилось:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>me.nyanguymf.java.bukkit.console</groupId>
  <artifactId>console-server</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Java Bukkit remote console</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigot-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-repository</id>
            <url>file:///${project.basedir}/maven-repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.bluecube.thunderbolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>Thunderbolt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--=======================================-->
            <!--   Maven Shade plugin for executable   -->
            <!--    file and including dependencies    -->
            <!--=======================================-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>shade</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>io.bluecube.thunderbolt:*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--==============================================-->
            <!--    Maven Jar plugin for manifest creation    -->
            <!--==============================================-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>me.nyanguymf.console.server.ConsoleServer</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```